# Selecting different branches from Github, in the VB Application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, github

So on my Github Repository, I have two branches, one is Master, and one is Beta.

I was wondering if its possible to let the user who is using the application go and in the application select which branch they wanna use of the application.

Pretty much here's an example.

You go-to advanced settings.
On the bottom-left corner, select the Dropdown box.
Select Beta.
Application reloads, and the Beta Branch loads instead of the Master Branch.
(if this makes sense, trying to describe what I mean best I can.)

Comment: Is this WinForms, Console, WPF?

Comment: Potentially.  We have something similar in our internal development, but it required a lot of new files/command prompt actions to know which current branch to pull down.  So yes, it is possible. Not easy though, and will most likely require an experienced individual to set up.

Comment: @Sasha It's WinForms, Vb.net 

and JohnPete22, Yeah, I figured it would probably not be the easiest thing to do, but considering I am the only one who works on the project, I was hoping maybe it would be something I could manage to do.